# DataGridView jumps to the top after scrolling and clicking

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvvm, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with filtering. When the filter is applied the scroll position is returned to the top and the data in the grid is updated as expected. When I then scroll down using the scroll bar then click on a row, the scroll jumps back up to the top again and the wrong row gets selected. Then I scroll down again and click, no reset. This is the behavior I expected.

I understand why the first jump occurs because the grid has effectively been rebound to a new source. However, why it jumps back up again after scrolling and clicking is a bit vexing. I have tried using both a BindingList and a BindingSource. I have tried calling all sorts of update and refreshes and position resets on the DataGridView to try to induce the second reset programatically instead of when the user clicks. Any ideas?

The only other wrinkle is that I'm using the MVVM pattern with databinding to approximate the knockout.js we use on the web. Functionally, this shouldn't differ from something like txtPartNumberQuery_OnChanged(){RebindGrid();}

I figured this out right after I took the time to write it up, so... I suppose I'll answer my own question.

View Model:

```
public string PartQueryString { 
    get
    {
        return _partQueryString;
    } 
    set
    {
        _partQueryString = value;
        //observe this value and trigger a search when it changes
        this.PartMaster.DataSource = _model.SearchPartMaster(_partQueryString);
    }
}
```

View:

```
private void ConfigureGridView()
{
    gvPartMaster.AutoGenerateColumns = false;            
    gvPartMaster.Columns.Add(Common.Helper.GetBasicGridViewColumn<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn>("Number", "Part Number"));
    gvPartMaster.Columns.Add(Common.Helper.GetBasicGridViewColumn<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn>("Description", "Part Description" ));
    gvPartMaster.Columns.Add(Common.Helper.GetBasicGridViewColumn<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn>("ManufacturerDescription", "Manufacturer" ));
    gvPartMaster.Columns.Add(Common.Helper.GetBasicGridViewColumn<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn>("CategoryDescription", "Category" ));
    gvPartMaster.Columns.Add(Common.Helper.GetBasicGridViewColumn<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn>("Specs", "Specs"));
    gvPartMaster.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;

    gvPartMaster.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}

private void ApplyBindings()
{
    txtPartNumberQuery.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewModel, "PartQueryString", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    gvPartMaster.DataSource = _viewModel.PartMaster;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- The databinding on the textbox is firing an extra time when it loses focus, even though the value hasn't really changed.
- Clicking on a scroll bar does not constitute a loss of focus.

If you put 2 and 2 together, you get that the datagrid is being rebound not when they adjust the scroll but when they try to click the row. As we all know, rebinding a datagridview resets the scroll back to the top.

My solution is to ensure the filter condition has changed before rebinding the gridview.

```
public string PartQueryString { 
    get
    {
        return _partQueryString;
    } 
    set
    {
        if (_partQueryString != value)
        {
            _partQueryString = value;
            //observe this value and trigger a search when it changes
            this.PartMaster.DataSource = _model.SearchPartMaster(_partQueryString);
            _view.UpdateGridViewPosition();
        }
    }
}
```

> Functionally, this shouldn't differ from something like txtPartNumberQuery_OnChanged(){RebindGrid();}

This is actually a poor assumption because the TextChanged event would not have fired twice the way the databinding does.